# Out of sequence data in sensor monitoring program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, sensors

I am logging data on a long term basis from four USB serial ports on a Raspberry Pi that ultimately  needs to get to another machine on the local network for further processing.  There are a couple of constraints that make this more complicated than it might seem.  All the approaches I've tried so far result randomly in either lost or misordered data.  I'm doing the programming in Python.  I'm sorry that the following is very long, but I wanted to fully describe the situation.

Here's an outline of the data:

a.  Each serial port connects to a sensor that outputs data for two measurement channels at 115.2kb (so eight data channels).  The data for each measurement consists of one line.  The two lines are sent from the serial device separately, not as one message.

b. Each measurement starts with a timestamp in the form "XXXX.xxxxxxxxxxx chX". The integer part is seconds starting at 1 and increasing indefinitely, and the fractional part is 11 decimal places (10 picosecond resolution).  The timestamp is followed by a unique identifier of "chA", "chB", etc. up to "chH" and the line ends with a newline.  The timestamp *is* the data -- it shows when a pulse was received from an external device.  Here's an example: "123.12345678901 chD\n"

b.  The nominal data rate is one measurement per channel per second.

c.  For each "stanza" of eight readings I can decree that all valid timestamps must be within +/-0.5 seconds from a median value.  The spread is usually more like a few microseconds so the 1 second range allows lots of margin for valid data.

d.  The timestamps in a stanza may span a second boundary, or all occur within one second (the phase relationship is arbitrarily established at start-up).

e.  There is no guarantee of the order in which the lines of data for each stanza are received.  Here is an example stanza:

```
1234.01231231231 chA
1234.02342342342 chB
1233.99999912345 chE
1234.03453453453 chC
1234.03213213213 chD
1234.04324324324 chF
1234.01234567890 chG
1233.99999954321 chH
```

This shows that:  (1) the data in a stanza may cross over integer seconds; (2) the data may not be received in channel order; and (3) the data is not always received in order of ascending timestamps.

I need to place the data in strict channel ID order (chA, chB, chC, chD, chE, chF, chG, chH) for each stanza.  The above example should be logged as:

```
1234.01231231231 chA
1234.02342342342 chB
1234.03453453453 chC
1234.03213213213 chD
1233.99999912345 chE
1234.04324324324 chF
1234.01234567890 chG
1233.99999954321 chH
```

My current approach:

I have a serial.read() call running in a separate thread for each serial port, feeding a common queue that I process using an 8 item list initialized with all zeroes where each list item is associated with one channel (e.g., list[0] is chA, list[1] is chB, etc.).  As each line of data comes in, the timestamp is placed in the appropriate slot for its channel.  When the list no longer contains any zero values, the stanza is complete and I iterate the list from chA to chH to output each value, and then zero it for the next stanza.

The problem:

This generally works but I randomly end up with data getting out of sequence -- e.g., the serial data for one channel is missed for one second, so its slot in the list is filled with the next timestamp a second later.  Sometimes a whole stanza will disappear (though this is rare).  My guess is that problem results from the serial data is coming in asynchronously with random processing delays that cause values to be missed (testing has established that the serial data is actually being sent to the RPi; the loss is happening in this processing).

I originally fed the data to a socket server so the remote computer (on the same network) could grab the data over the wire.  Thinking the network stack might be causing the problem, I tried writing the data locally on the RPi.  While that works better, I am still getting these missing and out-of-sequence samples.

So I'm looking for an approach that will either avoid whatever bottleneck is causing messages to be lost, or provide some kind of reassembler that can reorder data into the appropriate stanza(s).  I'm also not sure whether reading the four comm ports in individual threads is the best approach.  Any ideas will be much appreciated.  And again, sorry for the length of this question.

Thanks!
John

Comment: if measurements are being missed for one second, it suggests that a sensor did not sense the "pulse" - so the problem seems to be with the sensor, not the code processing the sensor data

Comment: Hi Bravo -- no, the sensor doesn't seem to be missing any pulses.  When I've logged the channels separately into separate files, there are no glitches found (in runs of over 500K seconds x 8 channels).  It's the processing to get the sequence sorted that seems to be causing the problems.  In the past I've captured each stream to a separate file and then combined them, but I'm trying to get rid of that step.

Comment: Probably something to do with bad logic in your code then

Comment: Hey @JohnAckermann, you could try splitting the code that reads the streams into sub-processes (using python's multiprocessing built-in module), as threads do share I/O scheduling while processes don't. Overall this seems like a logic/bottleneck issue in your code, as otherwise you would get zero data loss/miss when testing locally on the RPi. If you go with the process approach you can setup a "scraper" main process/thread that will get all the channel data from all processes every X time and push that to the server (even if incomplete).

Comment: @JohnAckermann Another approach would be setting up each channel to stream the raw data on its own and have a central Message Queue (MQ) system (like Apache Kafka, RabbitMQ etc) that will receive the raw data and order it into frames/blocks appropriately later spitting it out in the format you need.

Comment: Hi @Alex -- thanks for that suggestion!  I may have found the bottleneck (I'll explain in a comment below) but going to multiprocessing might be a good idea anyway.  And it's something new for me to learn!

Comment: I'm not ready to declare victory yet, but after some changes I have about 22 hours of glitch-free data logged locally on the RPi.  I think the problem was that I was still creating 10 threads and queues with socket listeners even though I was no longer using them.  That might have created enough overhead to cause   I ripped them out and that seems to have made the difference.  I'm going to let it continue logging for a while longer before I convince myself that the problem really is solved.

Comment: I collected about 240K x 8 data values without a hiccup after getting rid of the extra queues.  Alex, if I can figure out how to tag your suggestion of multiprocessing as an answer, I'll do that as I think that is probably the best solution to the problem.

Comment: @JohnAckermann, Don't sweat it, glad you figured it out and got it working, you can probably tag the comment as "adds something useful" with the button above the flag, but either way I wouldn't count that as a proper valid answer as both question and answer are lacking in detail about the code implementation itself. Cheers!